# QXmlStreamReader::isEndElement() returning false

Tags: xml, qt, qxmlstreamreader

Why is [QXmlStreamReader::isEndElement()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qxmlstreamreader.html#isEndElement) returning false when it encounters something like `<element/>` and how can I recognize an `<element/>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an empty element `<element/>` is parsed you should [see](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qxmlstreamreader.html#TokenType-enum) a `StartElement` token immediately followed by a `EndElement` token:

> The reader reports the start of an element with namespaceUri() and
>   name(). Empty elements are also reported as StartElement, followed
>   directly by EndElement.

But calling `QXmlStreamReader::isEndElement()` will always return `false` if positioned on a `StartElement` token, even if the element is empty.

Comment: Is there a way to distinguish between `<element>` and `<element/>` without `readElementText()`? I actually need to know how to proceed reading based on that.

Comment: @tobilocker not if positioned on the `StartElement` token

Comment: @tobilocker "I actually need to know how to proceed reading based on that." Are you sure? Something must be broken in the way your XML schema is specified, or in the way it's used, or perhaps with your understanding of XML. As far as the contents of an XML document are concerned `<el></el>` and `<el/>` convey the same information and must be treated as equal. The only purpose of `<el/>` is to reduce the size of the document, not to convey additional information!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, Qt's documentation says [this](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qxmlstreamreader.html#TokenType-enum) about empty elements, see section QXmlStreamReader::StartElement, so basically its immediate endElement after start, however if you try to do so it doesn't happen that way.
To achieve this you need to do .

Qt's Documentation for 'QXmlStreamReader::readNextStartElement()' says:     The reader reports the start of an element with namespaceUri() and name(). **Empty elements are also reported as StartElement, followed directly by EndElement.** **The convenience function readElementText() can be called to concatenate all content until the corresponding EndElement**. Attributes are reported in attributes(), namespace declarations in namespaceDeclarations().

So see the highlighted part of Qt's documentation for 'QXmlStreamReader::readNextStartElement()'
E.g.

```
<empty/>
<empty></empty>
```

Above is your two set of example of empty tag, which is same technically.

so what you need do is call below function this way you well get the start element for tag 'empty".

```
QXmlStreamReader::readNextStartElement()
```

Then you need to call below function which will take you to the end element of the specified start element.

```
QXmlStreamReader::readElementText()
```

Now if you call below function it will give you true

```
QXmlStreamReader::isEndElement()
```

There are some more complication to it and this is not a perfect solution, but i figured it out after some trial when i once faced this issue.

Comment: It would be helpful if you summarised the QT item, that you linked to, in the answer.

Comment: i have edited my answer and summerised Qt item, hope this helps.